# linq group by and select multiple columns not in group by

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select multiple columns not in a group by using linq - c#.

Using linq, I'm trying to group by ISNULL(fieldOne,''),ISNULL(fieldTo,'') and then select field_One, field_Two, field_Three for each group. So for each row that the group by would return, I want to see numerous rows.

So far I have the following, but can't seem to select all the needed columns.

```
var xy = tableQueryable.Where(
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cust.field_One)
            || ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(ust.field_Two)
            ).GroupBy(cust=> new { field_One= cust.field_One ?? string.Empty, field_Tow = cust.field_Two  ?? string.Empty}).Where(g=>g.Count()>1).AsQueryable();
```

Can somebody help pls?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to only select the fields that comprise the grouping key: all rows in one group will be identical. Not sure what you mean. Also, it seems you're using LINQ against some SQL backend. It's important to know which type of LINQ (like, Entity Framework + which version?).

Answer (score 7):

You are pretty much there - all you are missing is a `Select` from the group:

```
var xy = tableQueryable
    .Where(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cust.first_name) || ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(ust.lastName))
    .GroupBy(cust=> new { first_name = cust.first_name ?? string.Empty, last_name = cust.last_name ?? string.Empty})
    .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
    .ToList() // Try to work around the cross-apply issue
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(cust => new {
        Id = cust.Id
    ,   cust.FirstName
    ,   cust.LastName
    ,   cust.RepId
    }));
```

`Select` from each group does the projection of the fields that you want, while `SelectMany` dumps all the results into a flat list.

Comment: this looks great but I can't run. I get the following error.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: The query attempted to call 'CrossApply' over a nested query, but 'CrossApply' did not have the appropriate keys.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NestPullup.ApplyOpJoinOp(Op op, Node n)...

Comment: @MikeTurner I think there's an issue in LINQ2SQL/EF, you may want to insert `ToList`, say, after the second `Where`, so that grouping is done in memory. See edit.

Comment: @MikeTurner No, there would be only one DB call. Groups would be brought into memory row-by-row, then the final conversion to anonymous objects would take place in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
var groupsWithDuplicates = tableQueryable
    .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.first_name) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.last_name))
    .GroupBy(c => new { FirstName = c.first_name ?? "", LastName = c.last_name ?? "" })
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1) // Only keep groups with more than one item
    .ToList();

var duplicates = groupsWithDuplicates
    .SelectMany(g => g) // Flatten out groups into a single collection
    .Select(c => new { c.first_name, c.last_name, c.customer_rep_id });
```

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: The query attempted to call 'CrossApply' over a nested query, but 'CrossApply' did not have the appropriate keys.

Comment: It's trying to do a little too much in SQL.You can throw in a .ToList() to pull down your data and do the rest of the work with LINQ to Objects. See my edit above.

Comment: and this would be executing 2 database calls? I would not like that

Comment: You can always profile it to be sure. Something in the first version of the query was unsupported by your SQL provider (as dasblinkenlight also pointed out in his answer), so we can divide the work into two steps.  SQL does what it can, and then the rest of the code can take it from there. You just don't want to put the .ToList() too high, or you'll end up pulling down too many records (potentially).  I'm curious -- did that code edit work for you?  I can't really test it. :)

Comment: We're trying. The issue im having is that my tableQueryable really has lots and lots of columns, that's why I was trying to specify that I only need, first_name,last_name,customer_rep_id, and id. to do this, i need to generate entity framework code with a new function that does not have so many fields i think. agreed? bec now it's selecting so many fields and I'm getting timeout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117447/discussion-between-duane-theriot-and-mike-turner).

Answer (score -1):

For me I have used following query to do the filter Customer and get the customer records group by the JobFunction. In my case the issue get resolved after adding the .AsEnumerable() after the where solve the problem.

```
var query = _context.Customer
                 .Where(x => x.JobTitle.ToUpper().Contains(searchText.ToUpper())).AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(item => item.JobFunction,
                    (key, group) => new {
                        JobFunction = key,
                        CustomerRecords = group.ToList().Select(c => c).ToList()
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure what you think "the issue" is, but it's not OP's issue. In fact, the question is too vague to answer.