# Linq equivalent to a Sql Query

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

SQL Query -

```
select q.QuesId, q.Title, q.Description, count(a.QuesId) as Answers
from Question q
join Answer a on q.QuesId = a.QuesId
group by q.QuesId, q.Title, q.Description
```

I want to convert this Sql query to linq.

My approach is -

```
var questions = (from q in db.Questions
                 join a in db.Answers on q.QuesId equals a.QuesId
                 group q by new 
                 { q.QuesId, q.Title, q.Description, q.AskedBy, q.AskedOn, q.ModifiedOn }
                 into x
                 select new 
                 { x.Key.QuesId, x.Key.Title, x.Key.Description, x.Key.AskedBy, x.Key.AskedOn, x.Key.ModifiedOn, x.key.Answers.count }
                 ).ToList();
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402796/linq-group-by-and-select-multiple-columns-not-in-group-by) might be helpfull.

Comment: @CoderofCode Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Check the fluent syntax version if it helps, shall provide the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I end up doing which works well for me -

```
var questions = db.Questions
                .GroupJoin(db.Answers, q => q.QuesId, a => a.QuesId, (q, a) => q)
                .GroupBy(q => new { q.QuesId })
                .SelectMany(x => x.Select(q => new 
                { q.QuesId, q.Title, q.Description, q.UserDetail.FirstName, q.UserDetail.LastName, q.AskedOn, q.ModifiedOn, q.Answers.Count }
                )).Distinct();
```

Comment: If you want Left Join instead of Inner Join, then its important to create the Default for the unmatched records, which is quite feasible, in your case you are using only Left part of Join , so can be skipped but quite common mistake. Beside that grouping one key doesn't require new or curly brackets and finally GroupBy on multiple keys is a better approach than flattening up using SelectMany

Comment: Also please note Distinct on a anonymous type is not a good idea, you shall be able to create a  class and override Equals, GetHashCode as you implement IEquatable